# Redis Cluster Mode With 1 Node?

Tags: redis

Is it possible to run redis in cluster mode with a single primary/secondary node?

If the primary and secondary node lose contact, how do they decide who is the new primary node?

Do I have to run a 3rd sentinel service to watch both nodes and decide which to promote?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to run redis in cluster mode with a single primary/secondary node?

Yes, you can. By assigning all slots to a single node. However, it's a very BAD deployment. It makes things complicated, and has no benefit than a single instance Redis.

> If the primary and secondary node lose contact, how do they decide who is the new primary node?

Since there're no other primary nodes, there won't be a leader election. So the primary node will always be the primary node, and the secondary will always be the secondary.

> Do I have to run a 3rd sentinel service to watch both nodes and decide which to promote?

NO. Redis Sentinel has nothing to do with Redis Cluster.